# How can i do select multiple rows ( allowMultipleSelection="true" ) in datagrid using flex?

Tags: php, apache-flex, flash, datagridview, datagrid

I have id(array) used in my application . i want to select number of rows mathching given array but if i used gatagrid selected Index then it will be selected only one row only . i set data grid allowMultipleSelection="true" also .. . how can be select mutipule rows in datagrid ? please refer me

```
for(var i:int=0;i<id.length;i++)
        {

            datagrid.selectedIndex=id[i];
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If id is an array of integers, you should be able to do this:

```
datagrid.selectedIndices = id;
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting them through selectedItems instead that allows you to set multiples.